# Padding still causes width of container to change with border box box sizing

Tags: css

I have a flex div container with three child divs. For some reason adding padding left to the first container - #testcont causes the other containers to move. Unless I'm not looking carefully, why is this happening when the box-sizing is border box?

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/templar9901/2g3whovc/2/

```
<div id = "three">
    <div id = "testcont">
        blahh1
    </div>
    <div>
        blahh2
    </div>
    <div>
        blahh3
    </div>
</div>


//CSS

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#three{
    border: solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#three div{

    border: 2px solid red;
/*  flex-grow: 1; */
    
}

#testcont{ 
    padding-left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: it's because `justify-content: space-around;` will re-arrange the items to adjust for the total space which now is smaller.

Comment: box-sizing play no role since there is no width defined

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, this makes sense and is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Because they all share the same parent container.

You should put each group with a different style separately like this.

```
<div id = "main-container">

<div class="container1">
    <div class="btn" id = "testcont">
      blahh1
    </div>
 </div>
 
<div class="container2"> 
      <div class="btn">
        blahh2
      </div>
      <div class="btn">
        blahh3
      </div>
  </div> 
  
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-container{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.container1 {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container2 {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}
.btn{

    border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0 5px;
  
/*  flex-grow: 1; */
}

#testcont{ 
    padding-left: 30%;
}
```

hope this help.